# DexIndexOverflowException android

Tags: android, build.gradle

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexWithDexForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: Cannot merge new index 67217 into a non-jumbo instruction!
```

I have 2 applications code with common code as library. When I give command assembleRelease from gradle, it gives this error. 1 apk is generated for 1st app but 2nd app apk is not built.

Comment: Use this https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html for your second app

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your **project.properties** file

```
dex.force.jumbo=true
```

and make sure you are not using whole **google play services** library for single task.

and if you further face any problem similar to multidex then hit this
[Link](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)
and if you need assistance related to google play services hit this [link](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

Comment: I think it was multidex issue. I used it in both app and now it is working. Thanks!